# How to schedule a Python Selenium script in the background?

Tags: python, selenium

So I have a Python Selenium script that opens chrome, gets information, and then closes. My script is done, and I want to run it daily every 5 minutes. But how do schedule the script to do that? And how to make sure that the browser doesn't open every 5 minutes, but just does it on the background. (Or maybe on a server?) I am new to programming so could anyone describe it very detailed how to do it? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Regarding running the script on a schedule, you are looking for a [cron job](https://linuxize.com/post/cron-jobs-every-5-10-15-minutes/).

`how to make sure that the browser doesn't open every 5 minutes, but just does it on the background.`

-- for this, I'm not sure what binding language, browser, or initilization setup you are using, but I think you want to run the browser in `headless` mode.

Comment: Should my computer stay on the whole time then?

Answer (score 0):

To make sure the browser opens in the background you can use Selenium's headless chrome option like this

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Chrome(CHROMEDRIVER_PATH, options=options)
```

To make the script run in interval you will have to use something like `crontab` for Linux or `Windows Task Scheduler` for windows